# Help understanding double integral with three variables over a curved surface.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I need to calculate $$\int\int_{S} x^2yz^4 dA$$ whereas $$ S: z=4-x^2-y^2 \\ x\geq0\\z\geq0$$ I suspect that I should use the fact that the function is odd "with respect to $y$", but what I'm having trouble is determining the boundaries. 
Since $S$ is a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, I don't understand how one should take the slope of the surface in $z$-direction into account when determining the boundaries.

My second question is how do you double integrate a function with three variables? Will the answer contain a $z$ ?

Comment: Your integral is a surface integral https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral

Comment: Given the boundaries set forth by the problem, the odd property will not be of any use to you. Also, there is probably a constraint missing because as is, the integral is over an unbounded surface and will diverge.

Comment: @NinadMunshi you're right, had the wrong constraint: y>0 should be z>0.

Comment: @popi, how do I parametrize the surface?

Comment: Then draw a picture - the integral must be zero, can you see why?